# How to extract numbers from string and if there are more than one, add them together?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel spreadsheet

[image]

I have a set of over 10,000 lines of text strings in column A (Input), and I need to get the number (in case there is only one) or a sum of both (in case there are two).

---

**Code**

Here is the VBA code I have:

```
Sub ExtractNumericStrings()

Dim rngTemp As Range
Dim strTemp As String
Dim currNumber1 As Currency
Dim currNumber2 As Currency
Dim lngTemp As Long
Dim lngPos As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet

    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each rngTemp In .Cells(1, "A").Resize(lngLastRow, 1) ' Set Range to look at
        strTemp = rngTemp.Value2 ' Get string value of each cell
        lngTemp = Len(strTemp) 'Get length of string
        currNumber1 = 0 ' Reset value
        currNumber2 = 0 ' Reset value
        ' Get first number
        currNumber1 = fncGetNumericValue(strTemp, 1) ' Strip out first number
        ' Get second number if exists
        ' First strip out first number
        strTemp = Replace(strTemp, currNumber1, "")
        If Len(strTemp) <> 0 Then
            currNumber2 = fncGetNumericValue(strTemp, 1)
        End If

    ' now paste to sheet

        If currNumber1 <> 0 And currNumber2 <> 0 Then
            rngTemp.Offset(0, 1).Value = currNumber1 + currNumber2
            rngTemp.Offset(0, 2).Value = "sum of the numbers"

        ElseIf currNumber1 <> 0 Then
            rngTemp.Offset(0, 1).Value = currNumber1

        End If

        Next rngTemp

    End With

    Call MsgBox("Procedure Complete!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Procedure Complete")

End Sub



Private Function fncGetNumericValue(strTemp As String, lngStart As Long) As Currency

Dim varTemp As Variant
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim lngTemp As Long

' Reset

lngCount = 1
lngTemp = 1
varTemp = ""

On Error Resume Next

If IsNumeric(Left(strTemp, lngCount)) Then
    Do While IsNumeric(Left(strTemp, lngCount)) = True
    varTemp = Left(strTemp, lngCount)
    lngCount = lngCount + 1

    If lngCount > Len(strTemp) Then
        Exit Do
        End If
        Loop
    Else
        ' First clear non-numerics from string
        lngTemp = 1
        Do While IsNumeric(Left(strTemp, 1)) = False
        lngTemp = lngTemp + 1
        strTemp = Mid(strTemp, 2, Len(strTemp) - 1)
            If lngTemp > Len(strTemp) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        ' Then extract second number if exists

        If strTemp <> "" Then
        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(strTemp, lngCount, 1)) = True
        varTemp = Left(strTemp, lngCount)
        lngCount = lngCount + 1
            If lngCount > Len(strTemp) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
Loop
        End If
    End If

    ' Retrun Value

    If IsNumeric(varTemp) Then
        fncGetNumericValue = CCur(varTemp)
    Else
        fncGetNumericValue = 0
    End If

 End Function
```

---

Here is what I'm trying to do: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EjHnJVxuWJA

---

I have very limited knowledge of VBA, so please excuse me if I ask any stupid question. Running this thing successfully will save me hips of time. thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a little better in the post, I cant access the links from work.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I've reformated the post, is it better now?

Comment: Indentation would be nice, and get rid of all this blank lines. And please put something in the title that summarizes your question - everyone asking a question is seeking help.

Comment: Why is the first result 117.82? You might want to look into regular expressions (though you might not want to).

Comment: If the number is at the beginning then in VBA you can just use Val() which will ignore subsequent characters. Regional settings, though, would need to account for the comma separator, I believe.

Comment: @SJR typo I'm guessing. The 2nd column is `Intended Output` not actual output.

Comment: You have provided a sample of input & expected output, and you have provided some code. However, you haven't explained what's _wrong_ with your code. Where does it go wrong? Do you get compile or run-time errors? Is it not calculating correct answers? Something else wrong with it? Do you just want it to run faster or be written better (i.e. a Code Review)?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub extract_num()

   Dim cell as Range
   Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' replace Sheet1 with ur sheet name
   Dim lr as Long: Set lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim values() As String
   Dim i as Byte
   Dim temp as Double

   For Each cell in ws.Range("A2:A" & lr)

      If Not isEmpty(cell) Then
           values = Split(cell, " ")
           For i = LBound(values) to UBound(values)
              values(i) = Replace(values(i), ",", ".")
              If isNumeric(values(i)) Then
                  temp = temp + values(i)
              End If
           Next i
           cell.Offset(0, 2) = temp
           temp = 0
      End If

   Next cell

End Function
```

This is presuming:

- a) Individual words and numbers are always separated by space `"123 abc 321"`
- b) Commas "`,`" are used as an arithmetic floatpoint separator `##,##`

Comment: Neat, this might well work and simpler than I anticipated. Just requires there to be a space between the numbers.

Comment: @SJR yeah I kept that mind, even made it a footnote in my answer. With the examplary data provided it should work, though hard to tell without knowing the full data. Actually speaking of which, I'm not entirely sure - is there a case when `##,##` is valid `Double` format, or is it always supposed to be converted to `##.##`? In that case, might as well add the `Replace()` line to answer

Comment: It’s normal practice in some countries for numbers but as this is text the replace probably will be necessary.

Comment: That does assume there is no number formatting involved.

Comment: @SJR afaik the comma `,` is valid format only inside worksheets, but not inside vba. But I wasnt' entirely sure. But yeah, it's probably better to convert it so we don't get Type mismatch errror

Comment: But these are effectively strings (I assume).

Comment: Ditto.  Sadly would need more specification in the question, so this is probably the closest we can get to a definitive answer :)

Comment: @SJR Just as future clarification, out of curiosity, i edited my windows settings to have `,` as my float separator. Even then, although worksheet defaults to `##,##`, inside the vba code `IsNumeric("3,14")` returns `False`, meanwhile `IsNumeric("3.14")` returns `True`, regardless of the separator settings

Comment: Wouldn't this miss the **6** in `6ohyc`?

Comment: @Zac I'm not familiar with azbuka (russian alphabet), but I presume the 6 there is supposed to be part of the word, rather than the actual representation of number 6. But yes, the code in its current form would skip over `6ohyc`

Comment: Obviously, solution would be to extract only numbers from individual expressions and then add them together.

Comment: :) neither am I. Just posted an answer that presumes that 6 is a number in that string.. you are probably right :)

Comment: @Zac yeah, I upvoted so we have both cases covered :)

Comment: Re settings, I think VBA always uses US settings which use `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach from Rawrplus

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateTotals()

    Dim aRawValues As Variant
    Dim iLRow&, iRow&, iArr&
    Dim dTotal#

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<-- Change the sheet name to your sheet

        iLRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row                 ' Get row count

        For iRow = 1 To iLRow                                       ' Loop through all rows in the sheet

            aRawValues = Split(.Range("A" & iRow).Value, " ")       ' Create and array of current cell value

            For iArr = LBound(aRawValues) To UBound(aRawValues)     ' Loop through all values in the array

                dTotal = dTotal + ReturnDouble(Replace(aRawValues(iArr), ",", "."))     ' Add the returned double to total

            Next

            .Range("B" & iRow).Value = dTotal                       ' Set value in column B
            dTotal = 0#                                             ' Reset total

        Next

    End With

End Sub


Function ReturnDouble(ByVal sTextToConvert As String) As Double

    Dim iCount%
    Dim sNumbers$, sCurrChr$

    sNumbers = ""
    For iCount = 1 To Len(sTextToConvert)
        sCurrChr = Mid(sTextToConvert, iCount, 1)
        If IsNumeric(sCurrChr) Or sCurrChr = "." Then
            sNumbers = sNumbers & sCurrChr
        End If
    Next

    If Len(sNumbers) > 0 Then
        ReturnDouble = CDbl(sNumbers)
    Else
        ReturnDouble = 0#
    End If

End Function
```